# jQuery - set div width equal to height

Tags: jquery

I have a div that will always fill 100% of the browser height. Now I want to set its width to the same value (including screen resizing).

html:

```
<main>
  <div id="mainCircle">
  </div>
</main>
```

css:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mainCircle {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mainCircle').width($('#mainCircle').height);
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('#mainCircle').width($('#mainCircle').height);
  })
})
```

If I pass in the value for `$('#mainCircle').width` as a number - for example 100px this will work, but not dynamically. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in jQuery [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) is a function, not a property

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        $('#mainCircle').width( $('#mainCircle').height() );
    }).trigger('resize');

});
```

Comment: why would you trigger resize again?

Comment: @zfrisch - because I removed the line in the OP's code that sets the height on first pageload, and just triggered the event instead

Comment: It gets around writing out the same statement twice (once on ready, again per resize). The function that runs on resize is manually triggered immediately when the DOM is ready.

Comment: The alternative would be to move the inline anon function to a named function and call it onload and on resize.